# How I can determine the "nearest" exception handler

Tags: c++, exception

From [[except.throw]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#2):

> When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest
> handler with a matching type ([except.handle]); **“nearest” means the
> handler for which the compound-statement or ctor-initializer following
> the try keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control and
> not yet exited.**

First of all, I really can't understand this quote properly, and how it is applied in a particular code. So any understandable explanations, with simple words, will be very appreciated.

Consider this two code snippets:

```
/ * code A */

try
{
  throw 1;
}
catch (int) // nearest handler for throwing 1. #first_handler
{
}

-----------------------------------------------

/* code B */

try
{
  try
  {
    throw 1;
  }
  catch (int) // nearest handler for throwing 1. #second_handler
  {
    throw 2;
  }
}
catch (int) // nearest handler for throwing 2
{
}
```

Because I cannot understand the above quote, I don't know how I can determine the nearest handler, and I cannot apply `[except.throw]/2` in the above examples. My question is just how does `[except.throw]/2` is applied in the above code? or in other words, why `first_handler` and `second_handler`are nearest handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions travel upwards, hence you can look for the next `try` then see if it has a matching `catch`, if not continue. For example

```
try {                                  // 4
    try {                              // 2
        throw "foo";                   // 1
    } catch(int) { }                   // 3
} catch(...) {                         // 5
    std::cout << "hello exception";
}
```

When the excpetion is thrown in `1` then control flow goes backwards and the first `try` is the one in `2`. It does not have a matching `catch`, it only catches `int` (`3`). Hence, you look further upwards to find the `try` in `4`. It has a `catch` that catches any exception `5` and that is the "nearest".

---

> [...] "“nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement following the try keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control and not yet exited." What that's "not yet exited"? I can't get the bold part.

Thats the second example:

```
try            // try 2
{
  try          // try 1
  {
    throw 1;
  }            // <---- the try block is exited here
  catch (int)  // catch 1
  {
    throw 2;
  }
}
catch (int)    // catch 2
{
}
```

`throw 2` will be handled by `catch 2` because thats the nearest handler. The nearest handler is not `catch 1` because that belongs to `try 1`. And  when `throw 2` is executed then the `try 1` block is already exited.

Comment: Thanks. But can you provide a hint on *"“nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement following the try keyword **was most recently entered by the thread of control and not yet exited.**"* What that's "not yet exited"? I can't get the bold part.

Comment: @0x0 see edit. Once you are outside of the `try` block, its `catch` blocks cannot catch an exception anymore

Comment: Excuse me, another question to ensure. There's a wording in cppreference said that "When throwing an exception, an exception object is copy-initialized from throw-expression" And that's OK for me but it's then said: "then the control transfers to the exception handler with the matching type **whose compound-statement was most recently entered and not exited by this thread of execution**." That point just gets me a headache. At the point of throwing an exception, the handler compound-statement is not yet entered, but it will, so how the control will enter a scope that does not actually begin?

Comment: @0x0 sorry, I dont really understand the question and have problems to answer. My advice: Don't get too much hang up on wording in the stadard (cppreference tries to be as close as possible to the standard). Its written for compiler writers and implementers of the standard library. What actually happens is often simpler than what it looks.

Comment: "What actually happens is often simpler than what it looks" You're true, and that's really what gets me a headache. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @mada cppreference missed "following the try keyword" bit, which was actually important since there are two kinds of "compound-statement" in the page it links to in its "exception handler" link. I've added it